# Flutter Listen Mqtt Server in Background

Tags: flutter, push-notification, background, mqtt, flutter-workmanager

I am working on controlling IOT devices from Flutter. IOT devices run with MQTT server and in Flutter I need to listen Mqtt server in background and according to coming messages, I want to push notification. I already tried [WorkManager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) it connects MQTT in background but not listen. I think it works only one. I saw another solution [writing native solution](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124) but it is so complicated and I dont understand. Is there any way to get handle it? I dont want to use extra server for that. Ex: Firebase messaging or OneSignal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flutter_background_service and flutter_local_notifications packages. You will listen api and when a message coming , you will show a notification , and when user click the notification , you can show page what you want and  when app running at resume lifecycle, function will still working and you can listen with StreamBuilder widget (with on function)4

package adress = 'https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service'

You can ask your question to me, I will answer

Answer (score 0):

If your MQTT server supports [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) you can use websocket for your implementation, see https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/web-sockets

Comment: but how can I listen it in background? My problem is I can listen it in app workking but I need to work it in background.